# Complex inequality $\left|z-1\right|+\left|z+1\right| \le 3 $

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove or disprove such that $\left|z-1\right|+\left|z+1\right| \le 3 \Leftrightarrow  \left|z^2-1\right|\le 2$

---

i think  using AM $\ge$  GM it can be solved but i cannot do that ..
thanks for helping 
$\frac{\left|z-1\right|+\left|z+1\right| }{2}\ge \sqrt{ \left|z^2-1\right|}$

Comment: How do you propose using $AM\geq GM$? Adding such details shows people you have put in some effort and they will be more likely to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} i.$

Then you will see:

$$\left|z-1\right|+\left|z+1\right| =3.$$

But

$$\left|z^2-1\right|> 2.$$

Comment: Ha!  You disproved the converse to what I disproved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true even for real numbers.  Just take $z=\pm\sqrt{3}$.  Then $|3^2-1|=2$ but $|\sqrt{3}-1|+|\sqrt{3}+1|=2\sqrt{3}\approx 3.4641$.